# debootstrap centos under ubuntu?

Tags: debootstrap

I am needing to compile an app under an older version of CentOS.
I once found a way of doing a debootstrap style process for it.

Can anyone recall the name of the program and how you set it up for chroot?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for an answer, you can use `yum groupinstall` on RHEL based distros as follows:

```
yum -y groupinstall "Base" --installroot=/your/path/ --releasever=6
```

"Base" for minimal centos installation